# jquery opacity не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, html5

В шапке подключены js:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

После jquery подключаю свой файл и пишу там:

```
$(".portfoliolist").ready(function(){
    $(".portfolio, .card, .mix_all").css({"opacity":"0"});
});
```

Ожидаю что при загрузке страницы, этому блоку применится свойство и он скроется, но этого не происходит, и в консоле ошибок нет. Что я делаю не правильно.

Это код дива, который хочу скрыть при загрузке страницы:

```html
<div class="portfolio card mix_all" data-cat="card">
  <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <a href="images/port-7.jpg" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  swipebox" title="Image Title">
      <img src="images/port-7.jpg" />
      <div class="b-wrapper">
        <h2 class="b-animate b-from-left    b-delay03 ">Привет! я див который не получается скрыть.</h2>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Несмотря на то, что код `$(".portfoliolist").ready` вводит в заблуждение, ибо на самом деле выполнится `$(document).ready`, но в целом код работает: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9czye5a/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
    $(".portfolio.card.mix_all").css({"opacity":"0"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio card mix_all" data-cat="card">
  <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <a href="images/port-7.jpg" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  swipebox" title="Image Title">
      <img src="images/port-7.jpg" />
      <div class="b-wrapper">
        <h2 class="b-animate b-from-left    b-delay03 ">Привет! я див который не получается скрыть.</h2>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```